# Quaterion capitalization difference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I was writing some unity 2d Quatarion Rotation code, but after completing, it gave some errors, then, i capitalized 2 Q's in 2 "quaternion" keywords, and the code started working Just fine. Can Someone please tell the difference between capitalized Q and small q quatarion ( as in **Q**uatarion and **q**uaterion)

i fixed the capitalization in the 2 Q's and the code started working all of a sudden. i have tried searching on google but came short.

Here is the code snippet i wrote:

```
 private void HandleRandomDirectionChanges()
    {
        changeDirectionCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (changeDirectionCooldown <= 0)
        {
            float angleChange = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-90f, 90f);
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleChange, transform.forward);
            TargetDirection = rotation * TargetDirection;

            changeDirectionCooldown = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 5f);
        }
        
    }
```

before, the Word Quaterion, then i fixed it. i dont know How it fixed itself, but it did.

Comment: [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) is the name of a type in UnityEngine. `quaternion` is just a word. Programming languages are generally case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a case-sensitive language.

Unity provides a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) class, which starts with a capital Q. Your code needs to match that exactly in order to use it.

There are some places in C# where there are lowercase versions of capitalized things, such as `String` being aliased to `string`, but these are fairly unusual.

You are using other case-sensitive identifiers correctly already, so you're actually used to this. The `float` type must be all lowercase and `Time` must be capitalized.

So you are aware of the correct technical language here - Quaternion is a class, which is code, not a [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/), which is a predefined language feature.